# Angular 4 / RxJS, send HTTP of an array in sequence

Tags: angular, rxjs, flatmap

Trying to http post items of an array one after another in sequence. Knowing should use RxJS flatMap but couldn't make it work. Basically I need something like this:

item is an element of an array named items, want to go through the array and send each item.

```
    this.http.post(url, item)
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
            // call the same http.post again to send the next item
          },
          (error) => {
            this.app.error(error.json() as Error); // exit
          }         
        )
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe try [concat](https://netbasal.com/rxjs-six-operators-that-you-must-know-5ed3b6e238a0#1aaa)

```
Rx.Observable.concat(...items.map(item => this.http.post(url, item)).subscribe(res => doSmthWithResponse());
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. "ng build" complains "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>[]'." on following code:

Observable.concat(items.map( (item:Item) => this.http.post(url, item))
            .subscribe(response => this.doSomething() ) );

Comment: you forgot to add "..." (spread operator) in front of items.map. try Observable.concat(...items.map( (item:Item) => this.http.post(url, item)) .subscribe(response => this.doSomething() ) );

Comment: Really didn't know spread operator, thank you. But got exactly the same error with this code: Observable.concat(...items.map( (item:Item) => this.http.post(url, item)).subscribe(response => this.doSomething() ) ); Should the issue be in my import: 
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/concat'; Any other import? Thank you very much.

Comment: you miss one closing parentheses before subscribe, try this: Observable.concat(...items.map( (item:Item) => this.http.post(url, item))).subscribe(response => this.doSomething() ) );

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.http.post(url, item).map(res => res.json())
            switchMap(this.http.post(url1, item).map(res => res.json()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using from and flatmap

```
Observable.from(items)
    .flatMap(item => this.http.post(url, item))
    .subscribe({
        res => console.log("your response"),
        error => console.log("your error"),
        () => doSomethingAtEnd()
    });
```